# ODE using Weierstrass's P function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-curves

I need a hint for the following problem.

"Solve $(x')^2=x^3 − 3x^2 − 4x + 12$ with the initial with initial condition $x(0)=3$".

I know I should somehow use Weierstrass's $P$ function because it satisfies the equation $(P')^2=4P^3+aP+b$. I tried first to obtain the lattice corresponding to the elliptic curve above but without and success.

Comment: Is this a trick question? $x=3$ is a critical point and thus the solution to the IVP should be $x(t) =3$. Right?

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

1. The translation $x \mapsto x+1$ transforms the cubic polynomial on the RHS to a [depressed cubic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Reduction_to_a_depressed_cubic).
2. An appropriate scaling should produce the coefficient '4' for $x^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Weierstrass's function is the simplest way to a closed form. Nevertheless, the ODE can be solved in terms of Elliptic integrals, which are more commonly used.

[image]